# How to add a slight slide in/out in effect to the following jQuery animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the following to show an element on `hover` and hide it when the mouse leaves it:

```
$(".hidden").hover((function() {
  $(".hidden").stop(true, true).delay(100).animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 100);
}), function() {
  $(".hidden").stop(true, true).delay(2000).animate({
    opacity: 0
  });
});
```

Now, I would like to add a subtle slide in/out effect: left to right when it appears and right to left when it disappears. Right now the element is `230px` the fade in/out can only occupy `30px`. How to accomplish that?

Comment: what is the CSS of the `.hidden` element ? better yet, how about a working demo ? (http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be animating it's `margin-left` property from left to right and right to left.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/6mz25x56/1/)

#### jQuery:

```
$(".hidden").hover((function () {
    $(".hidden").stop(true, true).delay(100).animate({
        'opacity': 1,
        'margin-left': '0px'
    }, 100);
}), function () {
    $(".hidden").stop(true, true).delay(2000).animate({
        'opacity': 0,
        'margin-left': '-30px'
    });
});
```

#### CSS:

```
.hidden {
    height: 40px;
    width: 230px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is using `margin` better than using `width`?

Comment: Beacuse you said --------> _"slide in/out effect: left to right when it appears and right to left when it disappears"_